# Rx - How to unsubscribe automatically after receiving onNext()?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

How to unsubscribe automatically after receiving onNext() ?

For now I use this code:

```
rxObservable
.compose(bindToLifecycle()) // unsubscribe automatically in onPause() if method was called in onResume()
.subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
     ...
     @Override
     public void onNext(Object o) {
         unsubscribe();
     }
 });
```

Comment: The question requires more context in order for others to help you answer it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I you want to "unsubscribe" just after the first event, the operator `take` is a way to go.

```
 rxObservable.compose(bindToLifecycle())
             .take(1)
             .subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the "first()" is what I need.

Comment: there is a subtle difference between `take(1)` and `first` : `first` emit an error with an empty stream. `take(1)` doesnt. (so you have to check which one you'll need, regarding the context)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
 rxObservable.compose(bindToLifecycle())
             .takeFirst(lifecycleEvent -> lifecycleEvent == LifecycleEvent.PAUSE);
```